# some websites not opening completely

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, browser, modem

I am using bsnl broadband connection
modem: wa3002g1 
os: xp(86x) / vista(64x) 
A few days back I have changed the modem (don't know the previous model no) because of some issues. Since then I am not able to open most of the websites in Firefox, IE6/8, chrome, opera. If i connect with other network like reliance data card, those websites are opening, if i connect bsnl the problem will be same again. I called to customer care many times, but no use. Please help me to find the solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: any specific errors?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've narrowed it down to the router/modem. Loading the sites from another network works. Loading the sites from your bsnl network worked on the old modem but not the new. If you still have the old modem, try it once more. Moving from the premise that it is the new modem that's the problem...I'm assuming the modem is also a router.

1. Start simple - reboot the modem/router. This will force the device and your broadband provider to renegotiate the connection and perhaps solidify any device updates that may have happened.
2. Using the modem's web interface, turn off all firewall capability and test. If your can't find a way to turn off firewalling, look for a DMZ Host config. Set your test computer's IP as the DMZ. What you want here is to make sure your router isn't filtering or content blocking.
3. Your broadband provider may have associated your connection with the hardware MAC address of your old modem. Though rebooting the modem should have reset this possible association, look for a modem config where you can specify the MAC address that the broadband provider sees. Set it to "this device's MAC" if it's not and reboot. Otherwise try setting it to the MAC of your old modem (should be written on a label on the device itself).
4. Skip the router altogether (if it's a separate device) and connect a computer straight to the modem.
5. Make sure the modem/router has updated software/firmware.
6. Some ISP's require you run setup software. It's total BS but maybe you'll need to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use another network, take your laptop to a library or use a neighbours wifi (ask first).

Can you use both routers, the one that works first, then the newer one if its better, like a stronger wifi signal.